# Save all items of an array to a Firestore array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore, codable

This function saves data into Firestore.

```
static func createRecipe(docId:String, ingredientsAmount:Int, ingredientsName:String, completion: @escaping (Recipe?) -> Void) {
        
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("recipes").document(docId).setData(
            [
             "title":title,
             "ingredients": [
                ["amount": ingredientsAmount,
                 "name": ingredientsName]
             ]
            ]) { (error) in
             }
    }
```

I'm using Codable to parse the data from an external source. But I have only been able to save *one item at a time* from the `ingredients` array.:

```
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let recipe = try decoder.decode(Recipe.self, from: data!)

                    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
                    
                    createRecipe(
                        docId:uuid,
                        title: recipe.title ?? "",
                        ingredientsAmount: Int(recipe.ingredients?[0].amount ?? 0), // How to save EVERY item in recipe?
                        ingredientsName: recipe.ingredients?[0].name ?? "", // How to save EVERY item in recipe?
                    ) { recipeURL in
                        print("success")
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error parsing response data: \(error)")
                }
```

I can tell that I'm parsing the JSON data successfully because the following outputs every item in the `ingredients` array:

```
                    for eachIngredient in recipe.ingredients! {
                        print(eachIngredient.name)
                        print(eachIngredient.amount)
                    }
```

How can I save **every** item in the `ingredients` array to Firestore?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest passing an array of `Ingredient`s to the function and then using `map` to create the dictionaries:

```
static func createRecipe(docId:String, title: String, ingredients: [Ingredient], completion: @escaping (Recipe?) -> Void) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("recipes").document(docId).setData(
        [
            "title": title,
            "ingredients": ingredients.map { ["name": $0.name, "amount": $0.amount] }
        ])
        { (error) in
            //handle error
        }
}
```

Keep in mind that there's also a `setData(from:)` that takes a `Codable`, so since `Recipe` is `Codable`, you should just be able to do this (assuming `recipe` is a `Recipe` type):

```
try db.collection("recipes").document(docId).setData(from: recipe)
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) for the above function

Comment: The last comment about Codable was EXACTLY what I needed! What an elegant solution. Thank you so much!!!